# HTML/CSS Popup Window Fade

Tags: html, css

Ive seen sites where things like a login box will apprear, and the rest of the page will fade, buit the box stays the same.
How is this done?
Can someone please give me an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [link text](http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/)

And add following code on head section for faded background

```
<script language="Javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$.facebox.settings.opacity = 0.2
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the jquery lightbox /modal scripts to achieve the effect. There's lot of scripts that do what you are trying to achieve. My personal recommendations would be [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) (if you need something just for a login window) or ColorBox (if you need multiple overlays and require a lot of customization)